# Property is always nil in UIView's -drawrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I have UITableViewCell (grey background color) and it's subview (white background color) for represent horizontal timeline, and show time progress from 0 to 57 minutes as shown below:

[image]

Also this red round is a UIView with label on it, it is added as a property to a `timelineView`class (no outlet set).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLZGrandPrixLapView *lapView;
```

When data source updates with new time value, I send `[self setNeedsDisplay]`to redraw `lapView`. For renew label value and `lapView` position I have this code inside `-drawrect` :

```
self.lapView = nil;
[self.lapView removeFromSuperview];
self.lapView = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"RLZGrandPrixLapView" owner:self options:nil][0];
[self.lapView setLabelWithValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)self.currentLap]];
self.lapView.frame = CGRectMake(lapsWidthPointer + (kStartCoordinate - 10), -15, self.lapView.frame.origin.x, self.lapView.frame.origin.y);
[self addSubview:self.lapView];
```

Idea is to remove old `lapView` and to set and add new to a coordinates, according to new value. Before this I tried to check if `lapView`is equal to `nil` and it's always was nil. So everytime I update - I create new, but can't remove previous.
What am I missing here?

Comment: i wouldn't do that in drawrect, drawrect is for drawing stuff in the view, not for changing subview or adding views to it. It might called many times in situations you don't expect. Instead of removing and adding a new view just updating your subview would be much better.

Comment: also if you set `self.lapView` to `nil` you can't remove it from superview in the next line, because it is already nil then, so your old view will never get removed.

Comment: Thanks, @Bastian! But i tried to not nil property, just call -removeFromSuperview, and again, without success. I can't remove previous view.

Comment: you should not do that in drawRect. drawRect is for doing custom drawing (manipulating the graphic context) of the view. If you don't   do that, don't use that function.